# How do I trigger a form submission on page load using Jquery

Tags: jquery

This doesn't seem like it should be too difficult to accomplish, but I'm in a rush and I have been looking for a simple answer. I need to submit a form on page load. This is my AJAX submit function which works fine. I just need to figure out how to trigger it on page load.

Any help is much appreciated!

```
$("form#seller-agreement-form").submit(function() {  
        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below    
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "http://www2.myurl.com/formhandler",  
            data: "email="+ email + "&status=" + status,  
            success: function(){  
                $('form#seller-agreement-form').hide(function(){$('div#output').fadeIn();});  

            }  
        });  
    return false;  
    });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you call `$().submit()` it triggers the action; `$().submit(function)` binds a handler to the submit event.

You can skip the submit however and just call the ajax method directly.

```
$(function() {
  $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "http://www2.myurl.com/formhandler",  
      data: "email="+ email + "&status=" + status,  
      success: function(){  
          $('form#seller-agreement-form').hide(function(){$('div#output').fadeIn();});  

      }  
  });
});
```

Comment: In some circumstances, the form gets submitted without passing through the handler when you use `$().submit()` or even `$().trigger('submit')`. Probably an issue unique to me, but since we are programmatically submitting the form, a much more fool-proof way would be to trigger a click on the submit button. That way, the `submit` event would be as "natural" as possilbe.

Answer (score 4):

To actually submit the form on page load, you would write something like

```
$(function() {
   $('#seller-agreement-form').submit();
});
```

But if what you're trying to do is just to perform the same action that you would otherwise have performed when the form was submitted, then perhaps you don't want to submit the form, but only to do this:

```
function postForm() {
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "http://www2.myurl.com/formhandler",  
        data: "email="+ email + "&status=" + status,  
        success: function(){  
            $('form#seller-agreement-form').hide(function(){$('div#output').fadeIn();});  

        }  
    }); 
}

$("form#seller-agreement-form").submit(function() {
    postForm();
    return false;
});

$(function() {
    postForm();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function () {
    $("form#seller-agreement-form").submit(function() {  
        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below    
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "http://www2.myurl.com/formhandler",  
            data: "email="+ email + "&status=" + status,  
            success: function(){  
                $('form#seller-agreement-form').hide(function(){$('div#output').fadeIn();});  

            }  
        });  
    return false;  
    }).trigger('submit');

});
```

You can use the `.trigger()` function to trigger the `submit` event on the form. I chained the calls so the form only has to be selected once. Note, you want to make sure to set the `submit` event handler before triggering the `submit` event.

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/trigger

Comment: Ok. That worked, however I seem to be caught in an endless loop of submissions.

Comment: @VaughnD.Taylor The code above shouldn't loop, after the `.trigger()` function is called the `submit` event handler will run which does not trigger a `submit` event. So there is probably some other custom code you've written that's messing with the flow.

Comment: It's most likely looping because you are posting the form back to itself.  You may need to put an if() block around the .trigger(), and tag the URL with a param so that it will not post again.

Answer (score 0):

Call `$("#seller-form").submit()` on the form and this will trigger the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do

```
function AjaxCall() {
    // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www2.myurl.com/formhandler",
        data: "email=" + email + "&status=" + status,
        success: function() {
            $('form#seller-agreement-form').hide(function() {
                $('div#output').fadeIn();
            });

        }
    });
    return false;
}

AjaxCall();

$("form#seller-agreement-form").submit(AjaxCall);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function to trigger submit event in your document.ready event

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you're asking for

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form#seller-agreement-form").submit(function() {  
        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below    
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "http://www2.myurl.com/formhandler",  
            data: "email="+ email + "&status=" + status,  
            success: function(){  
                $('form#seller-agreement-form').hide(function(){$('div#output').fadeIn();});  

            }  
        });  
    return false;  
    });
});
```