# Submit form with data on load

Tags: javascript, jquery

This data on console `$(this).serialize()` gives me the result below, I wanted to submit it on load not on click and **pass a select default value programatically(currency_code)** --  the form is a built in library

```
 _method=PUT&source=geolocation_recommendation&return_to=%2F&currency_code=PHP
```

This is my code on click

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $(document).on("submit", "form.locale-bar__form", function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
        let data = $(this).serialize()
        console.log('>>>>', data)
      });
    });
```

Form looks like this

[image]

Comment: Use $("form.locale-bar__form").submit();

Comment: @ZlatinHristov edited, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing the point or is this not doing its job? :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".locale-bar__form").submit();
});
```

edit:
[might find your solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510343/how-do-i-trigger-a-form-submission-on-page-load-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Another HTML solution:

```
<html>
<body onload="document.locale-bar__form.submit()">
   <form action="#" name=".locale-bar__form">
      <!-- Your form here -->
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

edit:
You can add selected attribute to an option with jquery like this. So that it will make that option default.

```
$("select option[value='blabla']").attr("selected","selected");
```

Comment: the form is built in, need to add a select default value on load then submit it at the same time

Comment: add `selected` tag in your option that you want to be as default.

Comment: $(".locale-bar__selector").val('PHP');
 $(".locale-bar__form").submit();

doesn't seem to work

Comment: try this. I think you're not telling jquery the right select tag. `$("select[name='currency_code']").val('PHP'); `

Comment: and btw how can I check if the submit button triggers on load?